# Action not forwaded to tiles-definition from forward path in Action

Tags: tiles, struts-1

My struts-config.xml has a few forward actions that point to tiles definitions. But it takes path as it is given & doesn't directed to the tiles-definition.xml & showing path does not start with a `"/"` character

My struts-config.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">
<struts-config>
   <data-sources />
<form-beans >
   <form-bean name="feelSafeForm" type="com.feelsafe.struts.form.FeelSafeForm" />
</form-beans>
<global-exceptions />
<global-forwards >
   <forward name="login1" path="/feelSafe.do?do=login" />
   <forward name="admin" path="/feelSafe.do?do=admin1" />
</global-forwards>
<action-mappings >
<action
  attribute="feelSafeForm"
  input="/index.jsp"
  name="feelSafeForm"
  parameter="do"
  path="/feelSafe"
  scope="request"
  type="com.feelsafe1.struts.action.FeelSafeAction">

  <forward name="adminmainpage" path="feelsafe.adminmainpage" />
  <forward name="login" path="feelsafe.login" />

 </action>

</action-mappings>

<message-resources parameter="com.feelsafe.struts.ApplicationResources" />

<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
   <set-property property="definitions-parser-validate" value="true" />
   <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
   <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-definition.xml" />
</plug-in>

</struts-config>
```

tiles-definition.xml is :

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 1.1//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_1_1.dtd">     
<component-definitions>

<definition name="feelsafe.common" path="/feelsafeLayout/layout.jsp">
   <put name="title" type="string" value="FeelSafe Hospital"/>
   <put name="header1" value="/feelsafeLayout/header.jsp"/>
   <put name="footer1" value="/feelsafeLayout/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="feelsafe.login" extends="feelsafe.common">
   <put name="body1" value="/feelsafeJspFiles/login.jsp"/>
</definition> 

<definition name="feelsafe.admin" extends="feelsafe.common">
   <put name="body1" value="/feelsafeAdminJspFiles/adminlogin.jsp"/>
</definition>

</component-definitions>
```

When login is called, control goes to forward tag & gives `500 Error` saying :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception forwarding for name login1:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Path feelsafe.login does not start with a "/" character

Comment: Anything in the startup logs with logging set to DEBUG?

Comment: problem is solved, I didn't enter the <init-param> chainConfig in web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error when i removed this snippet from init params of my action servlet in web.xml

```
    ...
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
        <param-value>org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

So when you use an old version of dtd like 1.1 try to add this init-param to action servlet to your web.xml file.
I tested on 1.3